# URL Naming convention for fetching only a column from resource

Tags: microservices, naming-conventions, naming, conventions, url-pattern

I have a microservice endpoint that gets a list of company details from the DB. The URL pattern looks like this.

GET https://example.com/api/v1/companies

I need to develop another URL that fetches only the company names from DB. I understand I can reuse the same URL, but to fetch only one column i don't want to fetch all columns.

Please guide me how to have the url pattern for this case.

Ex: GET https://example.com/api/v1/companies/companyNames?

Answer (score 0):

We should not increase number of services exposed until it is really needed. I will recommend re-using the same service with format:

GET https://example.com/api/v1/companies?col=name

If col parameter is blank you can assume to return all columns. This will help you re-use the codebase; minimal changes; and lots of flexibility in future; and less confusion for end consumer.